# expression or phrase using bridge noun and take verb

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage, expression-choice

I would like to use 'be the bridge that takes someone' or 'be the bridge takes someone'.

i.e: **Company A wants to be the bridge that takes you to success.**

However, I am not sure if the expression above is natural or not. Could you please let me know if the usage of the expression/phrase is correct? Or are there any better expressions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound natural to me. It's wordier than it needs to be. "Company A wants to be your bridge to success" sounds more natural.

Comment: It doesn't sound natural because a bridge is an immovable object, it cannot take someone from point A to point B. A vehicle can take someone somewhere, but not a building. A bridge can CONNECT point A and point B, if OP really wants to use a verb.